# How to enable swagger image upload with nestjs?

Tags: swagger, nestjs, documentation, openapi

I'm facing problems to enable image upload select with nestjs

my implemetation:

```
@ApiOperation({ summary: 'Upload and update user avatar' })
  @ApiConsumes('multipart/form-data')
  @ApiBody({
    schema: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        file: {
          type: 'string',
          format: 'binary',
        },
      },
    },
  })
```

however this does not work, the swagger only informs that a binary must be sent, but does not enable the upload button.

Answer (score 1):

I' ll copy paste something from a project that I work, to your code.
In my case we used to upload pdf file, but I think that it will work in your case also.

Your controller should be like this:

```
import { UploadedFile, UseInterceptors } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FileInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { diskStorage } from 'multer';
import { editFileName, fileFilter } from './receipt-upload.util';

...

  @ApiOperation({ summary: 'Upload and update user avatar' })
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileInterceptor('file', {
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: './images',
        filename: editFileName
      }),
      fileFilter
    }),
   )
  @ApiConsumes('multipart/form-data')
  @ApiBody({ description: `The image file to upload`, type: ImageUploadDto })
  async uploadImage(@UploadedFile() file) {
    ...
  }

...
```

And the dto, should be like this:

```
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';

export class ImageUploadDto {
  @ApiProperty({type: 'string', format: 'binary', description: 'Image file to upload'})
  file: any;
}
```

And the util file should be like this:

```
import { extname } from 'path';
import { BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common';

// Allow image files
export const fileFilter = (req, file, callback) => {
  if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/)) {
    return callback(
      new BadRequestException('Only image files are allowed!'),
      false,
    );
  }
  callback(null, true);
};

export const editFileName = (req, file, callback) => {
  const fileExtName = extname(file.originalname);
  const randomName = Array(32)
    .fill(null)
    .map(() => Math.round(Math.random() * 10).toString(10))
    .join('');
  callback(null, `${randomName}${fileExtName}`);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, however the problem would not be intercepting the file, the problem is that swagger does not display the image upload button in my documentation